# Why function getRange in my Apps Script dont work?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet, phpspreadsheet

[image]

Can anyone help me with my problem please? Usually the syntax never error, but from yesterday the "getRange" always error and i dont know why. I made a new files and is still the same. can anyone help me please?

Comment: You must have renamed or deleted the sheet "Pemilihan Barang", please double check. Can you please post the codes as code snippet, instead of an image so it will be easy to copy and and share the sheet file this script is bound to so we can replicate it (Please remove any sensitive information on your sheet).

Comment: thankyou so much for your respond, but at first it works and then when i continue my works, it didn't work again. the syntax on .range is not able to be read. here's the snippet that you wish for, i hope you can help me with my problem sir:)

https://snipit.io/public/snippets/64539

Comment: can you share a copy of the spreadsheet file without any sensitive data?

Comment: Okay thankyou for your respond, this is the link that you need it for. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GKpsHX-5-t4Q0j1xAqeO0b0MmXhtYkwkgcflPV5r_1Q/edit?usp=sharing . maybe you can try it to for a couple times because sometimes it works, and sometimes it doesn't. thankyou so much for your help!:)

Comment: are you having problems with the getRange or the .range? These 2 are different. For .range is not able to read this is most likely because you are using onEdit function. The onEdit triggers automatically upon  changes on any cell. It is not meant to be run from script, it will most likely fail because it requires the e variable which is only created upon making edits. Running it from the script will not generate the e variable therefore causing the Cannot read property 'range' error. Reference: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/93768249/problem-with-range-in-a-function?hl=en

Comment: okay i get it, but why sometimes it works and sometimes it's not trigger for the syntax? can you tell me the reasons? is it because of the internet connection is not stable or not? once again thankyou for your help sir!

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the error log? It should not be able to run since you are not returning any e obj from running the script manually. It could also be possible that you've accidentally changed the function that you are running which is why you were able to run it.